# Autodie fools syntaxcheck of perl

Tags: perl

Seems as if depending on the version of perl, autodie masks some syntax-errors.

In Perl 5.16.0:

```
$ perlbrew use 5.16.0
$ perl -c check_netapp_pro/lib/Il/Nagios/test/xx.pm 
String found where operator expected at check_netapp_pro/lib/Il/Nagios/test/xx.pm line  10, near "croak "stop""
(Do you need to predeclare croak?)
syntax error at check_netapp_pro/lib/Il/Nagios/test/xx.pm line 10, near "croak "stop""
check_netapp_pro/lib/Il/Nagios/test/xx.pm had compilation errors.
```

But in 5.10.1:

```
$ perlbrew use 5.10.1
$ perl -c check_netapp_pro/lib/Il/Nagios/test/xx.pm 
check_netapp_pro/lib/Il/Nagios/test/xx.pm syntax OK
```

The module *xx.pm* is:

```
package Il::Nagios::Store::Attribute;
use feature ':5.10';
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;

#use Carp;

croak "stop" if 0;

1;
__END__
```

The confusing part is that on some servers (e.g. CentOS 6.5, perl 5.10.1) the absence of `use Carp;` stops script execution even if `use autodie;` is present in the module.

Can anyone shed some light on this? How would you unit-test against such errors? ([Test::Strict](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Test-Strict-0.23/lib/Test/Strict.pm) did not detect the missing `use Carp;` statement).

Comment: Are you using the same version of `autodie` on both systems? If not, which version are you using in 5.10 and which in 5.16? NB: from changelog for `autodie`: "2.10  * BUGFIX: Fatal and autodie no longer leak Carp functions into the caller's namespace."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @i-alarmed-alien I could quickly determine the reason:

On my 5.10.1 perlbrew installation *autodie* is installed with version 2.06_01, the newer installation (perl 5.16.0) is using autodie in version 2.10 where a bug had been fixed, which leaked the Carp functions.

Just for the records: To determine the version of *autodie* (or any other module) just type

```
cpan -D autodie
```

Comment: For the record, there is a convention on CPAN that a release with an underscore in the version number (e.g.: the "2.06_01" you quoted) is a development release and not intended for use on production systems.  Usually the standard CPAN installer scripts would skip such releases unless you asked for a specific version.